# Javascript - Why does a function work on the last call only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Just started learning how to code. The first lesson taught how functions are used. For the below add function, whenever I call the function more than once, the output is displayed only for the last one. Does a function have to be written separately for each time I call?

```
function add(first, second) {
  return first + second;
}

add(1,2);
add(7,9);
add(3,5);
```

Output: 8

How can I get an output to all three?

Comment: If you're trying this in the console, then you only get the result of the *last* line. The function does work three times, though.

Comment: Add `console.log()` for each so `console.log(add(1,2));` and `console.log(add(7,9);` and so on.  You're getting the output from the console (not from a real running program) and it only shows you the output from the last line of code it ran.

Answer (score 1):

Your add function returns the computation, it does not print anything. So once you call it, all the work will be done and returned, and if you want to see what is returned, all you need is to console them in order to appear in the developer panel

```
function add(first, second) {
  return first + second;
}

console.log(add(1,2)); // <- HERE
console.log(add(7,9);
console.log(add(3,5));
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you are trying this on developer console. if you run this code as a file, you even doesn't get any output.

The developer console typically logs out the output from the codeblock. once the execution is done.

use `console.log()` in order to see all outputs.

```js
console.log(add(1,2));
console.log(add(7,9));
console.log(add(3,5));
```